# Python Pandas concatenate rows and sum up values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that look like this :

```
name    event_code_0    event_code_1100 event_code_1110 event_code_1120 event_code_1120 event_code_1199
0   A   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   A   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   A   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   A   0   0   1   0   0   0
4   A   0   1   0   0   0   0
5   A   0   0   0   0   1   0
6   A   0   0   0   1   0   0
7   A   0   1   0   0   0   0
8   A   1   0   0   0   0   0
9   B   0   0   0   0   0   1
10  B   0   0   0   0   1   0
11  B   0   0   1   0   0   0
12  B   0   1   0   0   0   0
13  B   1   0   0   0   0   0
14  B   0   0   1   0   0   0
15  B   0   0   0   1   0   0
16  B   0   1   0   0   0   0
17  B   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I would like to merge the differents rows on the column : 'name' and count the event code.

For instance the dataframe should look like :

```
name    event_code_0    event_code_1100 event_code_1110 event_code_1120 event_code_1120 event_code_1199
0   A   2   2   2   2   1   0
1   B   1   2   2   1   1   2
```

I have try different things with .merge but without success.
Maybe someone know an easy trick...

Cheers,
Astrus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), for `name` to column add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('name').sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
  name  event_code_0  event_code_1100  event_code_1110  event_code_1120  \
0    A             2                2                2                2   
1    B             1                2                2                1   

   event_code_1120  event_code_1199  
0                1                0  
1                1                2
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
print (df1)
  name  event_code_0  event_code_1100  event_code_1110  event_code_1120  \
0    A             2                2                2                2   
1    B             1                2                2                1   

   event_code_1120  event_code_1199  
0                1                0  
1                1                2
```

Comment: Glad can help. Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by the name column and take the sum:

```
df.groupby('name').sum()
Out: 
      event_code_0  event_code_1100  event_code_1110  event_code_1120  \
name                                                                    
A                2                2                2                2   
B                1                2                2                1   

      event_code_1120.1  event_code_1199  
name                                      
A                     1                0  
B                     1                2
```

This, by default, sets the name column as index. You can change that by:

```
df.groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
Out: 
  name  event_code_0  event_code_1100  event_code_1110  event_code_1120  \
0    A             2                2                2                2   
1    B             1                2                2                1   

   event_code_1120.1  event_code_1199  
0                  1                0  
1                  1                2
```

or `df.groupby('name').sum().reset_index()`.